# What does "data-v- mean?

Tags: html, dom

I have this code like shown in the image. Just saw it on a website but I dont understand what this "data-v-28...." stands for. I wanna learn some but I dont understand it and cant find an answer on the internet. 
It is on a website I just saw and I want to use a script to change the position of a certain division. But I need to understand how to move this division. I think that this part relates to it.

```
<div data-v-28f44f54 class="data-set">
<div data-v-28f44f54 class="type">
```

Answer (score 5):

It's just a [`data-*` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) used to store extra information on the `div` element. The DOM ignores it (other than storing the attribute on the element). Unless that extra information is used by some code on the page to position the div, it's unrelated to the div's position.